# How do i Parsing JSON in Php Seprate and loop through data

Tags: php, arrays, json, web

**Hey**,

I wanted to know that I am using an API, That API gives me the news in JSON format. Now I am making a Website that will have all those news. I cannot parse this JSON DATA, This is the URL that contains this data. 
[JSON LINK](https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=5d0d49e595dc4b64a2fd3916b617ad8c)

```
  {
    "status": "ok",
    "totalResults": 20,
    "articles": [
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "the-new-york-times",
                "name": "The New York Times"
            },
            "author": "http://www.nytimes.com/by/jonah-engel-bromwich, https://www.nytimes.com/by/vanessa-friedman, https://www.nytimes.com/by/matthew-schneier",
            "title": "Kate Spade, American Designer, Is Dead at 55",
            "description": "Ms. Spade was discovered in her apartment in Manhattan.",
            "url": "https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/05/fashion/kate-spade-dead.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2018/06/06/fashion/06spade/06spade-facebookJumbo.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T17:00:36Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "the-washington-post",
                "name": "The Washington Post"
            },
            "author": "https://www.facebook.com/amber.j.phillips",
            "title": "Paul Manafort could now be in even more trouble. That should worry Trump.",
            "description": "More legal pressure on Manafort=more chance he'll flip in the Russia investigation.",
            "url": "https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2018/06/05/paul-manafort-could-now-be-in-even-more-trouble-that-should-worry-trump/",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.washingtonpost.com/resizer/0YVxgDU7BlAuRmQ80mc3miYo5CI=/1484x0/arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/J3ICKYJOMQ6CNHGVZIHSRNPL7Y.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T16:51:02Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "reuters",
                "name": "Reuters"
            },
            "author": "Laila Bassam",
            "title": "Exclusive: In Syria, a Russian move causes friction with Iran-backed forces - officials",
            "description": "A Russian troop deployment in Syria near the Lebanese border this week caused friction with Iran-backed forces including Hezbollah which objected to the uncoordinated move, two non-Syrian officials in the regional alliance backing Damascus said.",
            "url": "https://www.reuters.com/article/us-mideast-crisis-syria-russia-deploymen/exclusive-in-syria-a-russian-move-causes-friction-with-iran-backed-forces-officials-idUSKCN1J125S",
            "urlToImage": "https://s4.reutersmedia.net/resources_v2/images/rcom-default.png",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T16:20:59Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Nbcsports.com"
            },
            "author": "https://www.facebook.com/RoobCSN/",
            "title": "White House drama could have destroyed other teams … but not these Eagles",
            "description": "All this White House drama could have destroyed other teams, but unity is what makes these Eagles so special. By Reuben Frank",
            "url": "https://www.nbcsports.com/philadelphia/eagles/white-house-drama-could-have-destroyed-other-teams-not-these-eagles",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.nbcsports.com/philadelphia/sites/csnphilly/files/2018/06/05/us_eagles_link_arms.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T16:17:21Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "newsweek",
                "name": "Newsweek"
            },
            "author": "Marie Solis",
            "title": "Bill Clinton Says He Got 'Hot Under the Collar' Answering Questions About Monica Lewinsky and #MeToo",
            "description": "Bill Clinton said he got \"hot under the collar\" when he answered questions about Monica Lewinsky on the Today show.",
            "url": "http://www.newsweek.com/bill-clinton-backpedals-monica-lewinsky-remarks-says-he-supports-metoo-959426",
            "urlToImage": "http://s.newsweek.com/sites/www.newsweek.com/files/styles/full/public/2018/06/05/bill-clinton.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T16:15:00Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "cnn",
                "name": "CNN"
            },
            "author": "Kevin Liptak, CNN",
            "title": "Putin says he and Trump speak 'regularly.' Here's how often that is.",
            "description": "Russian President Vladimir Putin said Tuesday he speaks \"regularly\" with President Donald Trump.",
            "url": "https://www.cnn.com/2018/06/05/politics/trump-putin-obama-phone-calls/index.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170723124529-putin-trump-split-0723-super-tease.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T16:15:00Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Latimes.com"
            },
            "author": "Associated Press",
            "title": "Only a few of Guatemala volcano's dead have been identified",
            "description": "Guatemalan authorities put the death toll at 69, but officials said just 17 had been identified so far because the intense heat of the volcanic debris flows left most bodies unrecognizable.",
            "url": "http://www.latimes.com/world/la-fg-guatemala-volcano-20180605-story.html",
            "urlToImage": "http://www.latimes.com/resizer/FbXh2zEF9Xm-uOiMCjQzve_4AQ0=/1200x0/www.trbimg.com/img-5b16ab3a/turbine/la-fg-guatemala-volcano-20180605",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T15:32:55Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "newsweek",
                "name": "Newsweek"
            },
            "author": "Jason Lemon",
            "title": "Crocodile Jumped Out Of Water And Killed Ethiopian Pastor During Baptism",
            "description": "Fishermen and members of the congregation did their best to help Docho Eshete, a Protestant pastor.",
            "url": "http://www.newsweek.com/crocodile-kills-pastor-baptism-ethiopia-959325",
            "urlToImage": "http://s.newsweek.com/sites/www.newsweek.com/files/styles/full/public/2018/06/05/gettyimages-481847798.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T15:14:00Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "business-insider",
                "name": "Business Insider"
            },
            "author": "John Haltiwanger",
            "title": "Police swarmed the home of high school shooting survivor and gun safety advocate David Hogg after prank phone call",
            "description": "The home of David Hogg, a survivor of the shooting at Marjory Stoneman Douglas High School, was \"swatted\" on Tuesday after a prank phone call told law enforcement there was a hostage situation at the residence.",
            "url": "http://www.businessinsider.com/home-of-gun-safety-activist-david-hogg-swatted-after-prank-call-2018-6",
            "urlToImage": "http://static.businessinsider.com/image/5b16a7e81ae66255008b4890-750.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T15:11:04Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "the-wall-street-journal",
                "name": "The Wall Street Journal"
            },
            "author": "Lingling Wei",
            "title": "China Offers to Buy Nearly $70 Billion of US Products to Fend Off Trade Tariffs",
            "description": "China offered to purchase nearly $70 billion of U.S. farm and energy products if the Trump administration abandons threatened tariffs, according to people briefed on the latest negotiations with American trade officials.",
            "url": "https://www.wsj.com/articles/china-offers-to-buy-nearly-70-billion-of-u-s-farm-and-energy-products-1528208835",
            "urlToImage": "https://si.wsj.net/public/resources/images/B3-AR363_CHINAU_SOC_20180605101801.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T15:02:00Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "the-washington-post",
                "name": "The Washington Post"
            },
            "author": null,
            "title": "Actually, Melania, your disappearance is a legitimate news story",
            "description": "The first lady’s office calls the news media ‘rabid’ for wondering why she has dropped out of sight.",
            "url": "https://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/style/actually-melania-your-disappearance-is-a-legitimate-news-story/2018/06/05/99294790-6813-11e8-9e38-24e693b38637_story.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.washingtonpost.com/resizer/nNEjVK-l32KhAFz0TwAxab3sCYI=/1484x0/arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/GDRD6ODIKAI6RHRYETTJHM4GG4.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T14:56:58Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "the-washington-post",
                "name": "The Washington Post"
            },
            "author": null,
            "title": "I saw what Maria did to Puerto Rico's hospitals. The death toll is no surprise.",
            "description": "Medical care, like everything else on the island, was virtually shut down after the storm.",
            "url": "https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/posteverything/wp/2018/06/05/i-saw-what-maria-did-to-puerto-ricos-hospitals-the-death-toll-is-no-surprise/",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.washingtonpost.com/resizer/cJ_w2hZJoT_niJfT-Lxfa4U5Yx0=/1484x0/arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/TM73JYEI2U36JHWOE5XHRJPLH4.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T14:36:24Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Startribune.com"
            },
            "author": "Paul Walsh",
            "title": "W. Minnesota woman's obit takes dark turn over long-ago extra-marital affair",
            "description": "\"She will not be missed,\" said brief notice that grabbed international attention.",
            "url": "http://www.startribune.com/w-minnesota-woman-s-obit-takes-dark-turn-over-long-ago-extra-marital-affair/484588991/",
            "urlToImage": "http://stmedia.stimg.co/KATHLEEN+OBIT.JPG?h=630&w=1200&fit=crop&bg=999&crop=faces",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T14:32:35Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "the-new-york-times",
                "name": "The New York Times"
            },
            "author": "Adam Nagourney",
            "title": "California Primary Election Live Updates: Democrats Play for GOP-Held Seats",
            "description": "This is a big Election Day in California, and the country is watching.",
            "url": "https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/05/us/politics/california-primary-elections-live.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2018/06/06/us/06cal-briefing01sub/06cal-briefing01sub-facebookJumbo.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T14:19:30Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "the-washington-post",
                "name": "The Washington Post"
            },
            "author": "https://www.facebook.com/jhohmann",
            "title": "David Koch is leaving Koch Industries, stepping down from Americans for Prosperity",
            "description": "His departure will change the makeup of one of the most active and well-funded political forces in the country that has been a bulwark in supporting Republicans.",
            "url": "https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/powerpost/wp/2018/06/05/david-koch-is-leaving-koch-industries-stepping-down-from-americans-for-prosperity/",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.washingtonpost.com/resizer/8_T_AplMQkWlnCKY1YjV5ZUcTpM=/1484x0/arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/NLFV5JNECY5THCNBBHUHUBCWJI.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T13:52:25Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Cnet.com"
            },
            "author": "Jessica Dolcourt",
            "title": "iOS 12: Siri Shortcuts, group FaceTime and 'Memoji' Animoji of you",
            "description": "Everything Apple announced for the iPhone and iPad.",
            "url": "https://www.cnet.com/how-to/ios-12-siri-group-facetime-memoji-and-more/",
            "urlToImage": "https://cnet4.cbsistatic.com/img/3R5HtavVDjD49BYit44jLYHx2TQ=/670x503/2018/06/04/b5fcbc71-cc14-4997-8d6b-258849f7c955/2018-06-04-10-55-39.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T13:09:11Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Charlotteobserver.com"
            },
            "author": "Ron Gallagher",
            "title": "FBI joins search for baby as focus shifts to eastern NC for girl abducted by sex offender",
            "description": "The case of Emma Grace Kennedy, a 7-month-old girl abducted Sunday from Virginia, took a strange twist Tuesday when police suspected a man reportedly trying to sell a baby in Durham, NC, might have been Carl Ray Kennedy, a convicted sex offender who police sa…",
            "url": "http://www.charlotteobserver.com/latest-news/article212475059.html",
            "urlToImage": "http://www.charlotteobserver.com/latest-news/yex0df/picture212552209/alternates/LANDSCAPE_1140/grace.png",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T12:48:40Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "usa-today",
                "name": "USA Today"
            },
            "author": "Erin Jensen",
            "title": "Miss America axes swimsuit competition; Gretchen Carlson says 'We are no longer a pageant'",
            "description": "Gretchen Carlson, Miss America Organization Board of Trustees Chair, had a major announcement on Tuesday's \"Good Morning America\": There will be no more swimsuit competition going forward.",
            "url": "https://www.usatoday.com/story/life/tv/2018/06/05/miss-america-swimsuit-competition-gretchen-carlson/672148002/",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.gannett-cdn.com/-mm-/d2d65a8ee91f20a09714e3a6a6550e1c79d7cc4a/c=0-593-2143-1804&r=x1683&c=3200x1680/local/-/media/2018/06/05/USATODAY/USATODAY/636637819845616797-GTY-954664126-99625691.JPG",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T12:23:00Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "the-washington-post",
                "name": "The Washington Post"
            },
            "author": "https://www.facebook.com/TomJackmanWP/",
            "title": "Did LA police and prosecutors bungle the Bobby Kennedy assassination probe?",
            "description": "Critics believe the police and prosecutors ignored evidence of two gunmen and pinned the case on Sirhan, leading Kathleen Kennedy Townsend to join calls for a new investigation.",
            "url": "https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/true-crime/wp/2018/06/05/did-l-a-police-and-prosecutors-bungle-the-bobby-kennedy-assassination/",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.washingtonpost.com/resizer/pOEENliV3eaP6uNcu5Ya1xq17D0=/1484x0/arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/RA4727Y34Q4WVDJNYH47G3QEIM.JPG",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T09:07:18Z"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Npr.org"
            },
            "author": "",
            "title": "In Narrow Opinion, Supreme Court Rules For Baker In Gay Rights Case",
            "description": "The Supreme Court on Monday ruled that a local baker in Colorado was within his rights to refuse to bake a cake for a same-sex couple's wedding, but it did not go beyond this case.",
            "url": "https://www.npr.org/2018/06/04/605003519/supreme-court-decides-in-favor-of-baker-over-same-sex-couple-in-cake-shop-case",
            "urlToImage": "https://media.npr.org/assets/img/2018/06/04/ap_17312739950081_wide-bec75df27909bee8722ae7c351074cc1e1157801.jpg?s=1400",
            "publishedAt": "2018-06-05T01:22:31Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

And My Php code is decoding this data to an array and then after that, I couldn't separate the objects and arrays. I know how much results i have and i can simply loop through it but i need to know how do i get that data .

```
    <?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=5d0d49e595dc4b64a2fd3916b617ad8c');


print_r( json_decode($json, true));
$jsons= ( json_decode($json, true));
echo $jsons[0]["article"];



?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP code is wrong, `echo $jsons[0]["article"];`. - This will not work.
You need to replace it with `print_r( $jsons["articles"][0] );`. Therefore, I think what you mean by JSON DATA is how you roll it out or going through the data.

Because you have set the assoc parameter to true, [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) will return an array.

First a correction to your code that hopefully help you to understand how json and [`array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) works.

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=5d0d49e595dc4b64a2fd3916b617ad8c');

print_r( json_decode($json, true));
$jsons= ( json_decode($json, true));
print_r( $jsons["articles"][0] );
echo $jsons["articles"][0]['title'];
```

In this example we will roll out all articles.

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=5d0d49e595dc4b64a2fd3916b617ad8c');
$news = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($news["articles"] as $i => $article) {
    echo '<h2>' . $article['title'] . '</h2>';
    echo '<img src="' . $article['urlToImage'] . '"/>';
    echo '<p>Published on ' . $article['publishedAt'] . '</p>';
    echo '<p>' . $article['description'] . '</p>';
    echo '<a href="' . $article['url'] . '">Read more</a>';
}
```

You may also want to see [array()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array.asp) at w3schools.com.

Comment: Great work like a charm. Well help me little more, For instance, I want to get the $json['totalResults'] but this does not seem to be working.

Comment: Replace `$json` with `$jsons` like so `$jsons['totalResults']`. You may want to rename the variable `$jsons` to `$news` to make it easier to understand.

Comment: `json_decode()` takes a JSON encoded **string** and converts it into a PHP **variable**. In your case a PHP array.

Comment: Yeah bro that was the problem, phew thank brah u helped me. quick question why everyone here is so rude that they just simple downvote as soon as I post anything.

Comment: I personally think that your question was unclear, but we got the hang of it. I think it's too easy to say that you can learn everything by just reading (by research). I also think that your question is only useless for experienced codes. So I would not downvote you and I do not agree with the community rules because there should be room for everyone just like 7 years ago :) . So I can not give you the clear reason why you've become downvote because I'm no longer interested in the community rules ;)

Comment: Like i have another account that got banned, i got the answers, i marked the answers, and even i am contributing in giving the answers to those who in need,But some people still come just to down vote the answer, recently i got banned for asking more questions . LIKE WHY ?

Comment: The community is only interested in quality content. This means that you must be able to answer the adequacy and the documents. In addition, the answer must be covered in a way that covers problems, crises and other things that the community believes is important. I can not answer why you have been banned, but you can read or ask about rules under Meta Stack Overflow https://meta.stackoverflow.com/. Meta Stack Overflow is about everything about the community.

Comment: answer the adequacy and the documents = respond adequately with documenting *** It is not enough to give the right answer :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1

Answer (score -1):

`$jsons` is not an array, but an object. What you want is `$jsons->articles[0]`.

Comment: It is an array because he have set the assoc parameter to true http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I forgot about that part. Should have been `$jsons['articles'][0]`. Thanks for the down vote by the way.